# AFTER UPDATE trigger that modifies the table on which it is defined

Tags: mysql, trigger

On MySQL 8.0  Trigger created:

```
DROP TRIGGER `Metrosky_spotters_2020_au`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `Metrosky_spotters_2020_au` AFTER UPDATE ON `Metrosky_spotters_2020` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Metrosky_spotters_2020 SET NEW.trnmswid = 5000;;
DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger  loads okay.
The function to edit a row but in a change to a field in that row- then t=fails the trigger functionality with:

> Can't update table 'Metrosky_spotters_2020' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

The idea here is to add the current users `MSWID` (or login) (using 5000 as test)  to  `trnmswid` whenever a row item is updated.

I've also tried this in `BEFORE UPDATE`  and still fails.

Is SET command incorrect or what am I missing?

Comment: The trick is to let the trigger modify the row that are about to be updated, see  mustaccio's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need, neither you can have (as the error message suggests), the `UPDATE` statement against the table on which the trigger fires. You can, however, directly set the value any `NEW` column in a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Metrosky_spotters_2020_au` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `Metrosky_spotters_2020` FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.trnmswid = 5000
```

Comment: So the above worked (as a test)- but here's the next step - add the correct syntax  substituting the '5000'   with the current_user . (that would be whomever is signed into the  database)  I've tried to get this to work but seem to run into syntax issues.

Comment: That would be a different question